# Passing image array values and changing image source onclick

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

OK, so finally the penny dropped (loud clunk!) on the click issue I was having here [Append dynamic div just once and a JSFiddle issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167952/append-dynamic-div-just-once-and-a-jsfiddle-issue). The code now shows user a choice of pics once per node clicked. Phew.

However, now my `img.src=e.target.src` line is having trouble accessing the other images in the array. Only the last image in the array will add to the table. I think this is because the `allImages.onclick` event should be inside the loop?

I have tried that and then `img` is showing up as undefined. I'm guessing that is because the loop (and therefore the function) is running before `var img` is declared? I think it is an issue with the order of things.

All help appreciated.

```
var makeChart = function () {
    var table = document.createElement('table'),
    taskName = document.getElementById('taskname').value,
    header = document.createElement('th'),
    numDays = document.getElementById('days').value, //columns
    howOften = document.getElementById('times').value, //rows
    row,
    r,
    col,
    c;

    var myImages = new Array();
    myImages[0] = "http://www.olsug.org/wiki/images/9/95/Tux-small.png";
    myImages[1] = "http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1139237954/just-logo_normal.png";
    for (var i = 0; i < myImages.length; i++) {
        var allImages = new Image();
        allImages.src = myImages[i];

        var my_div = document.createElement("div");
        my_div.id = "showPics";
        document.body.appendChild(my_div);
        var newList = document.createElement("ul");
        newList.appendChild(allImages);
        my_div = document.getElementById("showPics");
        my_div.appendChild(newList);
        my_div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    header.innerHTML = taskName;
    table.appendChild(header);

    header.innerHTML = taskName;
    table.appendChild(header);

    function addImage(col) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/tag-adobe.png";
        col.appendChild(img);
        img.onclick = function () {
            my_div.style.display = 'block';

            allImages.onclick = function (e) { // I THINK THIS IS THE PROBLEM
                img.src = e.target.src;
                my_div.style.display = 'none';
                img.onclick=null;
            };
        }

    }

    for (r = 0; r < howOften; r++) {
        row = table.insertRow(-1);
        for (c = 0; c < numDays; c++) {
            col = row.insertCell(-1);
            addImage(col);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('holdTable').appendChild(table);
    document.getElementById('createChart').onclick=null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem seems to stem from different parts. First of all,

```
for (var i = 0; i < myImages.length; i++) {
    var allImages = new Image();
    allImages.src = myImages[i];

    var my_div = document.createElement("div");
    my_div.id = "showPics";
    document.body.appendChild(my_div);
    var newList = document.createElement("ul");
    newList.appendChild(allImages);
    my_div = document.getElementById("showPics");
    my_div.appendChild(newList);
    my_div.style.display = 'none';
}
```

This loop creates a new `div` for EACH image in `myImages`, then appends a `ul` to that `div`, and finally appends the `Image` for the current image to the `ul`.

The question of what `document.getElementById('showPics')` returns, since there are as many `div`s with the `id` `showPics` appended to `body` as `myImages.length`, has a mystical magical answer which should never be spoken, or even thought, of again.

Why not do the sensible thing and create one singular happy `div` outside the loop? Append a single `ul` child to it, outside the loop. Then proceed to append as many `li` as you want in the loop.

```
var my_div = document.createElement('div');
my_div.id = 'showPics';
var newList = document.createElement('ul');
my_div.appendChild(newList);

for var i = 0; i < myImages.length; i++) {
    ...
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(allImages);
    newList.appendChild(li);
    ...
}

my_div.style.display = 'none';
```

Now, `my_div` is the one and only `div` containing the images. So, the `click` event handlers can toggle its visibility safely.

Second,

```
function addImage(col) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/tag-adobe.png";
    col.appendChild(img);
    img.onclick = function () {
        my_div.style.display = 'block';

        allImages.onclick = function (e) { // I THINK THIS IS THE PROBLEM
            img.src = e.target.src;
            my_div.style.display = 'none';
            img.onclick=null;
        };
    }
}
```

`allImages` references the same `Image` object now that you are out of the loop, which happens to be the last image in `myImages`. So, only the last image in `myImages` will register the handler to a `click` event. To solve this problem, we make a new variable.

```
var sel = null; //This comes before my_div
```

Now, we add the `click` handler to `allImages` **inside** the loop so that every image in `myImages` gets a piece of the pie, as they say.

```
for var i = 0; i < myImages.length; i++) {
    var allImages = new Image();
    allImages.src = myImages[i];

    allImages.onclick = function (e) {
      if(sel !== null) {
        sel.src = e.target.src;
        my_div.style.display = 'none';
        sel.onclick=null;
        sel = null;
      }
    };
    ...
}
```

And finally, adjust `addImage` so that `sel` can be set when the image is clicked.

```
function addImage(col) {
    ...
    img.onclick = function () {
        my_div.style.display = 'block';
        sel = img;
    }
    ...
}
```

That's all there is to it! **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NyxCu/12/)**.

Note that, if you comment out `sel.onclick = null`, you can change a particular cell's image as many times you like.

Comment: That's great Rikonator. Thanks for your help. It was driving me crazy. It is good to try these things for learning  purposes but when you're stumped it just becomes frustrating and turns you off the subject. I can see I was near yet quite far from the working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your `addImage()` function makes a direct reference to the `allImages` variable. One problem is that since you were using (and reusing) that variable in a for loop earlier in the code it is only going to retain the last value that was assigned to it. So no matter how many times you call `addImage()` it's always adding the `onclick` function to the last image that `allImages` pointed to.

I'd also suggest renaming the `allImages` variable. That's a very misleading name because it in fact only ever represents a single image.

Hope that helps!